# create cluster for existing mariadb database

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have an existing database for which i was looking to create a new clustered environment. I tried the following steps:

1. Create a new database instance (OS & DB Server).
2. Take a backup / snapshot from existing database server for all the databases.
3. Import the snapshot to the new server.
4. Configure the cluster - referred to various sites but all giving same solution. Example reference site - https://vexxhost.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-galera-cluster-with-mariadb-on-ubuntu-12-04/
5. Ran the command (sudo galera_new_cluster) on the primary server. (Primary server - no issue starting up). But when we tried starting the secondary server - it actually crashed for some reason.

Unfortunately at this point, dont have the logs stored / backed up with me where it failed. But it seemed like it tried to sync in with the primary server - had some failure with that.

As for additional part of the actions performed above. Both the server with same username / password - created a passwordless ssh connection between both the machines. Also, the method of syncing is set to rsync.

Am i missing something or doing it wrong? Is there a better way available on it?

Comment: What command(s) did you use to start up the other nodes?

Comment: Well - its like added the configuration as guided and then used the following in the first node - sudo galera_new_cluster --- to create the new cluster.

Second machine - it was just sudo systemctl start mysql. Probably that is how the documents / notes have been shared. So followed the same.

Comment: In this situation you have had to downtime on backup/restor step. So I search for ways to how fast backup and restore data, which no or less downtime.